# Samba "NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED" error when trying to image a Windows VM using Cobbler

Tags: windows, samba, imaging, cobbler, fedora-38

Looking for some help with Samba on Fedora 38.

We have a Cobbler v3.3.3 server currently for testing purposes.

We have configured Cobbler and managed to import a Windows distribution as per the instructions at https://github.com/cobbler/cobbler/blob/release33/docs/user-guide/wingen.rst#booting-from-bios-pxe-via-grub2-grub0-and-wimboot-tftphttp using PXE and BIOS mode.

We can get the first stage boot working where it loads the winpe.wim file.  However, when it reaches the stage of trying to map the network drive we get the following Samba error:

```
[2023/10/30 16:25:21.250168, 10, pid=6143, effective(1001, 1001), real(1001, 0), class=smb2] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_create.c:748(smbd_smb2_create_send)
  smbd_smb2_create_send: name [win10-x86_64\sources\setup.exe]
[2023/10/30 16:25:21.250281, 10, pid=6143, effective(1001, 1001), real(1001, 0), class=smb2] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_create.c:864(smbd_smb2_create_send)
  smbd_smb2_create_send: open execution phase
[2023/10/30 16:25:21.250720,  3, pid=6143, effective(1001, 1001), real(1001, 0), class=smb2] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3962(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../../source3/smbd/smb2_create.c:340
[2023/10/30 16:25:21.250859, 10, pid=6143, effective(1001, 1001), real(1001, 0), class=smb2] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3847(smbd_smb2_request_done_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_done_ex: mid [20] idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] body[8] dyn[yes:1] at ../../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:4013
```

We've tried multiple suggestions from various forums including setting up a user with a samba password and including the userid and password in the startnet.template file in Cobbler before doing a cobbler sync command.

Here is the basic Samba config the current Cobbler documentation recommends:

```
[DISTRO]
        path = /var/www/cobbler
        guest ok = yes
        browseable = yes
        public = yes
        writeable = no
        printable = no
```

These are the services enabled in firewalld:

```
cockpit dhcpv6-client http https samba ssh tftp
```

Any assistance with Samba and this issue, or someone with experience in setting up Cobbler to work with Windows distributions would be appreciated, as I'm new to Samba and my colleague hasn't touched Samba in a long time.

If any other information is required please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on Reddit of all places.  This needs to be added to the DISTRO smb share in smb.conf:

`acl allow execute always = yes`